# Return several list of items

Tags: java

I want to create a endpoint which returns several items which have the same category number:

```
 @GetMapping("item/{product_item_id}")
    public ResponseEntity<ProductFullDTO> getCategoryDetail(@PathVariable("product_item_id") Integer productItemId) {

        Map<Integer, ProductFullDTO> categoriesList = categoriesService.getProductItemList();

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, ProductFullDTO> entry : categoriesList.entrySet()) {
            List<Integer> list = entry.getValue().getCategories();
            if (list.contains(productItemId)){
                return new ResponseEntity<ProductFullDTO>(entry.getValue(), HttpStatus.OK);
            }
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
```

DTO:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class ProductFullDTO {

    private int id;

    .........
    private List<Integer> categories;
}
```

Data:

```
public Map<Integer, ProductFullDTO> getProductItemList() {

        Map<Integer, ProductFullDTO> list = new HashMap<>();

        list.put(1, ProductFullDTO.builder().id(1).title("Classes for Busy Dads").productItemVideo(1).categories(List.of(1)).summary("Summary").build());
        list.put(2, ProductFullDTO.builder().id(2).title("Classes for Busy Moms").productItemVideo(2).categories(List.of(1)).summary("Summary").build());
        list.put(3, ProductFullDTO.builder().id(3).title("Classes for Busy Kids").productItemVideo(3).categories(List.of(2)).summary("Summary").build());

        return list;
    }
```

As you can see into `ProductFullDTO` I can have several `categories` but curtly I can return only 1 of it matches the param from the Rest API request.

Do you know how I can return more than one items which match the `categories` number?

Comment: 1) create another list 2) add the matching values to the list 3) return the newly created list

Answer (score 0):

So, what you need to do, like @fantaghirocco already said, you need to:

1. Create a list of `ResponseEntity<ProductFullDTO>` and make your function return that list
2. In your function, add the things you want to return to that list
3. Return that list